# Convert CSV with dates using lubridate

Tags: r, date, csv, lubridate

I got a dataset in CSV format that has two columns: Date and Value.  There are hundreds of rows in the file.   Date format in the file is given as YYYY-MM-DD.  When I imported this dataset, the Date column got imported as a factor, so I cannot run a regression between those two variables.

I am very new to R, but I understand that lubridate can help me convert the data in the Date column.  Could someone provide some suggestions on what command should I use to do so?  The file name is: Test.csv.

Comment: See `?base::as.Date`

Answer (score 0):

Next time please provide some test data and show what you did.  For variations see `?as.Date` and `?read.csv` .  The following does not use any packages:

```
# test data
Lines <- "Date,Value
2000-01-01,12
2001-01-01,13"

# DF <- read.csv("myfile.csv")
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines)
DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date)
plot(Value ~ Date, DF, type = "o")
```

giving:

```
> DF
        Date Value
1 2000-01-01    12
2 2001-01-01    13
```

[image]

**Note:** Since your data is a time series you might want to use a time series representation.  In this case `read.zoo` automatically converts the first column to `"Date"` class:

```
library(zoo)
# z <- read.zoo("myfile.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
plot(z)
```

Comment: Also, you can do it as you read in: `read.csv(text=Lines,colClasses=c(Date="Date"))`

Comment: @thelatemail: does that work now? It didn't work in the past.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich - it most certainly does.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks very much.  I just used this command: library(zoo)
read.zoo("Test.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",").  The file opens fine, but when I select the linear model option under statistics / fit models [I am using R Commander]; I still see that "Date" appears as a factor, so I cannot run a regression.  The variable I am dealing with is energy efficiency; which is seasonal.  The idea behind running a regression is to see if there is a statistical relationship between time [date] and energy efficiency.

Comment: The answer contains a complete reproducible example including data and code and it works.  You likely have something else.  You really need to show sufficient data to make the question reproducible and also show what you tried when posting questions.  That is why readers are downgrading your question.